# Анимация на jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Скажите пожалуйста! Как можно объединить все эти функции и запустить их выполнение бесконечно?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#top").delay(5000).animate({left:"-=300px"}, 3000).delay(5000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text").delay(8000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000).delay(2000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 100);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text1").delay(8000).animate({left:"+=240px"}, 3000).delay(2500).animate({top:"-=30px", opacity:0},1000);
});
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#text2").delay(8000).animate({left:"-=240px"}, 3000).delay(2000).animate({left:"+=290px"}, 100);
});
```

Comment: тыщу раз уже было. 


ps: не надо делать `$(document).ready` на каждую команду, хватит одного раза.

Comment: Прошу извинения! Я выставил сырой вариант. Что можно сделать? Может через setaInterval или через циклы while или for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Официальная документация, страница [queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/#example-0), первый пример (показывает длину очереди, но функционал именно тот, что нужен)

```
var div = $( "div" );
function runIt() {
  div
    .show( "slow" )
    .animate({ left: "+=200" }, 2000 )
    .slideToggle( 1000 )
    .slideToggle( "fast" )
    .animate({ left: "-=200" }, 1500 )
    .hide( "slow" )
    .show( 1200 )
    .slideUp( "normal", runIt );
}
```

Можно еще сделать совсем по-красивому с замыканиями, когда функция runIt не видна из глобального пространства.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста! Почему он повторно не хочет выводить.Автоматом не получается.

    $(document).ready(function(){
  
    var car = $( "#top" );
    function runIt() {
      car
         .delay(5000)
         .animate({left:"-=300px"}, 3000)
         .delay(5000)
         .animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000);
    }
    runIt(); 
    });

Comment: Обратите внимание на последний animate.

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var car = $( "#top" );
        function runIt() {
          car
             .delay(500)
             .animate({left:"+=300px"}, 500)
             .delay(500)
             .animate({left:"-=290px"}, 500, runIt);
        }
        runIt(); 
    });

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLd44/)

Comment: Очень хорошо сделано! Только я хотел из начально не много другое. У вас движение идет автоматически с право на лева и на оборот.Помогите мне понять как можно сделать так, чтобы Объект проходя свой круг начинал его заново?

Comment: Слева направо, справа налево, а затем **начинает анимацию заново**. Последний аргумент в animate - это callback-функция, которая вызывается по завершении анимации.

Comment: Соль в том  что,  мне надо с право на лево, и опять с права на лево, и так бес конца. Как можно использовать эту функция обратного вызова?

Answer (score 0):

Через функцию window.setInterval(func|code, delay), примерно так:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.setInterval(animation, 17000);
});

function animation(){
    $("#top").delay(5000).animate({left:"-=300px"}, 3000).delay(5000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000);
    $("#text").delay(8000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 3000).delay(2000).animate({left:"-=290px"}, 100);
    $("#text1").delay(8000).animate({left:"+=240px"}, 3000).delay(2500).animate({top:"-=30px", opacity:0},1000);
    $("#text2").delay(8000).animate({left:"-=240px"}, 3000).delay(2000).animate({left:"+=290px"}, 100);
}
```